# Scrape image data with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape the images related to a product on amazon.com. How would I parse the image data?

I typically use the XPath. However, I was not able to locate the XPath for the images (besides the thumbnails). For example, this is how I parse the title.

```
title = response.xpath('//h1[@id="title"]/span/text()').extract()
```

The link to the item is: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N068GIX?psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N068GIX)

Comment: can you add a link to the page and specify which element you want to locate?

Comment: I added the link for the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like the images can be extracted from JavaScript that's present in the page source. I used [js2xml](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml) library to convert JavaScript source code to XML (you can learn more about it on Scrapinghub's [blogpost](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/01/19/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-part-1/)). The XML can then be used to create a `Selector` with which you can extract data as usual. Take a look at this example spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                         
import js2xml                                                                   
import scrapy                                                                   

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):                                             
    name = 'example'                                                            
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']                                            
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N068GIX?psc=1/']                

    def parse(self, response):                                                  
        item = dict()
        js = response.xpath("//script[contains(text(), 'register(\"ImageBlockATF\"')]/text()").extract_first()
        xml = js2xml.parse(js)                                                  
        selector = scrapy.Selector(root=xml)                                   
        item['image_urls'] = selector.xpath('//property[@name="colorImages"]//property[@name="hiRes"]/string/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

If you'd like to test it out, run it like

```
scrapy runspider example.py -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"
```

as Amazon seems to block Scrapy based on user agent string.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question says to use scrapy but here is a version of what you want using beautifulsoup, requests, and urllib. You also bypass the need to set the useragent using this method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests
from urllib import request

def load_image(url):
    resp1 = requests.get(url)
    imgurl = _find_image_url(resp1.content)
    resp2 = request.urlopen(imgurl) #treats url as file-like object
    print(resp2.url)
def _find_image_url(html_block):
    soup = bsoup(html_block, "html5lib")
    body = soup.find("body")
    imgtag = soup.find("img", {"id":"landingImage"})
    imageurl = dict(imgtag.attrs)["src"]
    return imageurl


load_image("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N068GIX?psc=1")
```